# Dynamic Link behaviour with no deep link mapped

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

In testing, some of the Firebase Dynamic Links pass the campaign/medium/source data correctly, while others don't.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the app (it is not available in my geo market either), so I cannot test directly. However,

- the links that pass the campaign data correctly point to the website homepage
- the links that don't are deep links

I suspect that it may be **missing deep link mapping** that's causing the issue.

Can anyone confirm it - or shed some light on it otherwise? Thanks.